# Get a list of property IDs from Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics-api

How do I go about enumerating the <s>profile</s> property IDs available as GA4 properties? I don't see any API endpoints for this in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

Comment: AFAIK, GA4 does not have profiles. Also, if you are looking to fetch GA4 Accounts, Web properties etc, you can refer the [Admin API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest)

Comment: @dikesh sorry I meant "properties" not "profiles".

Answer (score 1):

you can use this link its usefull to get account and if you iterate the account_id in it , it can iterate the information about properties along with ids.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list#python

```
service = build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

for account in accounts.get('items', []):
account_id = account.get('id')
account_name=account.get('name')
properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
    accountId=account_id
).execute()
```